# how to showing data to arraylist based on column value

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to show data based on column values, is that possible?

My adapter

```
public Cursor getDisease() {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            return db.query(TABLE_GEJALA, new String[]{
                            KEY_ID,
                            KEY_GEJALA,
                            KEY_PENYAKIT,
                            KEY_AREA,
                            KEY_KODE_PENYAKIT
                    },
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    KEY_GEJALA,
                    null);
        }
```

My activity then

```
private void loadListView(View view) {
    ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor c = sqliteHelper.getDisease();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            arrayList.add(c.getString(1));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList, true);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I am expecting to show code based on category

Comment: Does this cause an error? If so, please update your question with the error message. If not, update your question with the real output and expected output.

Comment: no sir, its not error, but the whole data show in one category. i want to filtering them to each category

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean. Please update your question with expected vs. actual output